# Get excerpt and permalink outside loop in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to get the post excerpt and permalink outside a wordpress loop, pulling the thumbnail and the title work fine but when trying to get the excerpt it doesn't work? And how would I get the permalink? My code so far is below.

Thanks!

```
<div id="featured">
            <?php 
                $ftid = 104;
                $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ftid) ); 
            ?>  
            <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" style="float:left;" />
            <div class="featured-info">
                <h2 class="post-title"><?php echo get_the_title($ftid); ?></h2>
                <?php $my_post = get_post($ftid); echo $my_post->post_excerpt; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And maybe if there is a better way of doing this you can point me in the right direction? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permalink should work as is:
    $permalink = get_permalink($ftid);

The excerpt though, when accessing the page object directly there actually has to be excerpt content (not just post content). If you didn't manually type in an excerpt on the post then nothing will appear. Inside the loop, the_excerpt() will automatically generate from the content if an excerpt hasn't been manually typed. Did you type a separate excerpt in the WP admin?

Comment: I did not, I've never seen an excerpt place? where is it? or is it just specific for each post?

Comment: When adding or editing a post, click "Screen Options" at the top and you can enable the "Excerpt" field.

Comment: Wow, I've never touched that tab in my life LOL

Answer (score 0):

Look at wp_get_attachment_url() - you left the $ off the name of the $ftid variable.
[image]